# How to programatically acces user.config file in AppData folder

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration

I'm trying to access the user.config file of another application in C#. I understand that I can use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()`.

I am talking about the user.config that is stored under `AppData\Local\MyApp`, not the configuration file I find in the same folder as the application.

Is this even possible?

The full path of the application data is in this form:

C:\Users\markn\AppData\Local\MyCompany\MyApp.exe_Url_pn34t01n4nbvali2df02umn4jhetpy0c\5.25.4969.26783

I just hope there is a call in the .NET framework somewhere that will allow me access to this file, without my having to resort to recursing all the directories looking for the file.

Thanks a lot.

Mark

Comment: Into the `locallappdata` environment variable, I don't have any file/folder "MyApp". Could you precise the path access please ?